# List of all system procedures and functions

Tags: sql-server

I need to fetch names, and if it possible - descriptions, of all system functions of the MSSQL server.

The procedure:

```
 sp_stored_procedures '%'
```

returns the list of procedures. But not all procedures. For example, the result list does not contain the procedure 'sp_cursor' and more other.

Is there a way to get the full list of procedures described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187961.aspx), and functions described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174318.aspx) by SQL Query?

Comment: This works fine: `SELECT * FROM sys.all_objects WHERE name = N'sp_cursor';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    sys.all_objects
WHERE is_ms_shipped = 1
and type in('p', 'fn', 'x')
```

To view all of them just remove the last 2 line so it becomes:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    sys.all_objects
```

Further reading:
[sys.all_objects (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178618.aspx)